# Characterization of Zero in a module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $M$ be an $R-module$ over a ring $R$.  Obviously, $0 \cdot m = 0,  \forall m \in M$.  Is it also true that $x \cdot m = 0,  \forall m \in M$ if and only if $x = 0$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_%28ring_theory%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R = \mathbb Z_6$ and $M = \mathbb Z_2=\{0,3\}$. Then $2m = 0$ $\ \forall m \in M$, but $2 \ne 0$ in $R$.

---

More generally, if $R$ is not an integral domain - say $xy = 0$ where $x \ne  0\ne y$, then if $M$ is the ideal generated by $y$ viewed as an $R$- module, then we will have $x\cdot m = 0$ $\ \forall m \in M$.

$R$ can even be an integral domain: $R = \mathbb Z$, $M = \mathbb Z_5$, then $x=5$ has this property.

---

If $M$ is a free module over $R$, then this cannot happen, since no element $m \in M$ can be linearly independent, as $x\cdot m =0$.

Comment: very good counterexample.  Thank you very much!